# Random value generation for a distribution

Tags: r, distributions

I wanted to get random values for a logarithmic distribution but I only have max and min values (and not the mean and sd). Is there a way to do this in R?

Comment: I'm assuming you first want to estimate the single parameter of the logarithmic distribution from a sample of size n that resulted in a minimum and maximum value and then generate random samples from a logarithmic distribution with that estimated parameter. If so, you'll also need to know n.

Comment: Further to @JimB's comment, that is because the [logarithmic distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_distribution) is unbounded to the right (so it *has* no maximum) and always has mass at 1 (so the minimum possible realization is always 1). So we assume you have a min and a max you *observed* from some sample of size $n$ and want to estimate the parameter $p$ from these three pieces of information, finally simulate from a logarithmic distribution with the estimated parameter.